# The HTML map tag as well as the js maphilight stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

I am making a web page and am using the map tag in it. My coordinates of the areas are correct but it is not working for some reason. I also have used the `maphilight` library which is not working as well. Also, the same code with different coordinates was working for a different image that I had used, but now it isn't. here is my html code:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <img src="/static/Images/Mosaic.png" alt="mosaic" usemap="mosaicMap" id="mosaicImg">
  <map name="mosaicMap">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" onclick="selectImage(1)">
      <area shape="rect" coords="100,0,200,100" onclick="selectImage(2)">
      <area shape="rect" coords="200,0,300,100" onclick="selectImage(3)">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,100,100,200" onclick="selectImage(4)">
      <area shape="rect" coords="100,100,200,200" onclick="selectImage(5)">
      <area shape="rect" coords="200,100,300,200" onclick="selectImage(6)">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,200,100,300" onclick="selectImage(7)">
      <area shape="rect" coords="100,200,200,300" onclick="selectImage(8)">
      <area shape="rect" coords="200,200,300,300" onclick="selectImage(9)">
  </map>
</div>
```

My image is 300 x 300 px
The function is not being called on clicking the area. Here is my js code for the `maphilight`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#mosaicImg').maphilight();
});
```

Here is the function called:

```js
function selectImage(imageNumber) {
    console.log("here");
    imageNum = imageNumber;
    inputImage.src = "/static/Images/Mosaic" + imageNum.toString() + ".png";
    laterNextText();
}
```

Please help me identify where am I wrong.

Comment: Did you include the plugin file in script tag? Any errors in browser dev tools console?

Comment: @charlietfl no errors. and yes I have included that file. In fact, I used almost same code for another image and it was calling the function.

Comment: Might have something to do with the inline `onclick`. Hard to help without a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I added the called function